# Jquery: How can I create color picker for contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, color-picker

My question is how can i do this, because i'm trying to do "simple WYSIWYG editor" and i succeed in doing changing font's size, weight etc. However I am still having problems with color picking. I have a table with cells with diffrent bgcolors. I wanted call for document.execCommand for every td inside the table. My problem is that the color of the text inside my *contenteditable* div is not changing. Even when i tried to add logging value of the colors i could read the value but still when i tried to change the color nothing happend. Am I doing something wrong? A piece of my table, and my code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #ffffff"></td>
    <td style="background-color: #ffccc9"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

$("#font-menu-color td").on("click",(function(){document.execCommand('foreColor', false, $(this).css("background-color"));}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here seems jquery returns color in RGB but the foreColor command needs it in hex.
quoting from mdn

> **foreColor**
>
> Changes a font color for the selection or at the insertion point. This
>   requires a hexidecimal color value string as a value argument.

click is mousedown+mouseup. On mousedown the editable area loses focus. If we add preventDefault on mousedown, the editable area keeps focus.

example here - example here - jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/474448

Comment: Even if i do smth like that it won't work: `$("#font-menu-color td").on("click",(function(){document.execCommand('foreColor', false, "#ff0707");}));`

Comment: i added event.preventDefault(); on mousedown. Now seems working. I saw that the time pressed the button the editable area loses focus.

Comment: It's working. But i think mine should work too. Maybe sb could explain it more? (btw. it's working with rgb colors)

Comment: nice :) click is mousedown+mouseup. On mousedown the editable area loses focus. If we add preventDefault on mousedown, the editable area keeps focus.

Comment: edit your answer, so i can mark it as helpful, because i can't mark comment as an answer